# How to speed up the consume time of ibm jms message

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

My application being as ibm client to consume the message which sent by ibm MQ server. But sometimes they will sent big number of messages(e.g:50000). But our client application can not "eat" the message so quickly.

what i'v been tried:

1. Use caching connection factory, But not help too much.

   org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory
2. I can't open multiple threads for the listener to speed up the consuming speed(Currently is set to 1) because of our business requirement.

Thanks in advanced!

Edit:

For each message processing time is like: (e.g:0:00:00.**079**) But wait to start process next message will take long time (e.g:0:00:00.**534**)

Comment: I suggest you have a thread which consumes the messages as fast as possible and pass these to a thread pool to process them. I also suggest you enable batching.  Unless your messages are large you should be able to process around 10,000 messages/second from any decent JMS server.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the transactional and persistence requirements of the messages.

There are a number of options within MQ that could be enabled here to speed up delivery.

MQ is optimized for either persistent/transactional or non-persistent/non-transactional workloads.  Don't mix them, so for example sending persistent messages in a non-transactional session.

If you are using non-persistent/non-transactional messaging then look into the READ_AHEAD options to stream messages down to the client.

In additional ensure that selectors are not in use.

Answer (score 0):

If the client implementation is negotiable, look at sending aggregate messages that combine individual messages, especially if the business logic can adapt to handle them together before (for example) saving something to a database.

The only legitimate "business" reason that you can't have multiple listener threads is because of event/workflow ordering and the chance of processing two related messages concurrently rather than sequentially.  However, perhaps it's possible to redesign the client so that messages are segregated by the sender, using JMS properties of some sort, and then have each listener filter by various properties.  As long as all related events/messages get the same property, you might be able to have multiple listeners.

Not ideal, but if you made the listener stateful so that you knew when to rollback event B because related event A is currently getting processed, that might work.  Difficult to do well with more overhead processing.  Better yet, figure out a way to process messages out-of-order and yet get the correct answer in the end.

Ultimately, for large number of messages, you really need to figure out how to get n listeners because otherwise you might never catch up and, worse case, continue to grow your backlog.